# how to present a question that each variable have 3 possible values in propositional logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

the question is we have 8 houses, their positions are

```
                                    A  B  C  D

                                    E  F  G  H
```

and each house can choose one wi-fi channel from three, and the neighbor (like A and B are neighbors, A and E are, but A and F are not) cannot use the same channel due to interference, use propositional logic to see if there is a solution.

If the question is each house chooses from 2 channels, then I can simply use 8 variables to be True / False to represent the 2 channels, but how should I do with 3 channels?

Comment: How about variables $A_1,A_2,A_3,B_1,B_2,B_3,...$?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand, can you explain it? how should I write the propositional logic formula?

Comment: $A_1$ means "house A uses channel 1", and so on. You'll need propositions for each house to express the requirement that each house uses exactly one of the three channels, and propositions for each pair of neighboring houses to express the no-interference requirement. (There are multiple ways to do it - maybe give it a try and update the question if you get stuck.)

Comment: This is my understanding, not sure if it makes sense: use A1 to represent if house A chooses channel 1, it's a True/False variable, and then use AB represents "house A choose different channel with house B", in propositional logic, it's very long: ((A1 and not A2 and not A3) and (not B1 and B2 and not B3)) or () or () or () or () or ()), means the six posssible ways. so this question is "AB and BC and CD and EF and FG and GH and AE and BF and CG and DF". Can you please have a look with my solution?

Comment: Yes, that works! You might be able to make it shorter by separating the "exactly one channel per house" requirements (e.g. $(A_1\land \lnot A_2\land\lnot A_3)\lor(\lnot A_1\land A_2\land\lnot A_3)\lor(\lnot A_1\land\lnot A_2\land A_3)$) from the "no neighbor interference" requirements (e.g. $\lnot (A_1\land B_1)$).

Answer (score 0):

You could translate the following MiniZinc model to propositional logic:

```
set of int: Channels = 1..3;
set of int: Rows = 1..2;
set of int: Cols = 1..4;

array[Rows, Cols] of var Channels: x;

constraint forall(c in Cols) (x[1,c] != x[2,c]);

constraint forall(r in Rows, c in 1..3) (x[r, c] != x[r, c+1]);

%  break symmetries by fixing the first two channels
constraint x[1,1] == 1;
constraint x[1,2] == 2;
```

Due to the symmetry breaking constraints, it results in $27$ solutions.
Without them, there are $27*6=162$ solutions.

Example solution:

```
 1, 2, 3, 1
 2, 3, 1, 2
```